# Angular2 после обновления страницы возвращает 404

Tags: angularjs, angular2, node.js, express

Не могу понять как настроить маршруты в `Angular2` + `Express`. Пытаюсь развернуть свой `angular2` проект на сервере. Сервер отдает пользователю `index.html`. Все маршруты работают. Если перезагрузить страницу появляется 404. Я понимаю, что каким-то образом надо передать маршруты из express в `angular`. Но нигде не могу найти как это делается. Пните в нужном направлении. Найденные решения не работают в связи с отсутствием `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`.

Comment: express должен на все запросы отдавать index.html, дальше ангуляр сам разберется. исключения составляют лишь запросы данных

Comment: Спасибо. Поправил express. Добавил обработку всех требуемых запросов.

Comment: проблема решилась?

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Немного не понятно как angular сам обрабатывает маршруты.

Comment: вместо добавления в заголовок, просто прими свой собственный ответ: галочка рядом с ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением в express server обработки всех маршрутов.

```
var renderIndex = function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
};
app.get('/*', renderIndex);
```